# link_to passing incorrect parameter to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an error on my set_project method in my projects controller. According to the error screen I am seeing, the parameters being passed are as follows:

{"project_id"=>"8", "id"=>"add_vote"}

I think the number 8 is what should be passed. Here is my projects controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_all_votes, only: [:show, :update]

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    @votes = Vote
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  def add_vote
    unless params[:project_id].nil?
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @newVote = Vote.create!(vote_value: true, user_id: current_user.id, project_id: @project.id)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Your vote has been recorded'} 
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project } 
        end
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_all_votes
      @votes = Vote.all
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title, :video_url, :description, :images, :team_name, :vote_count)
    end
end
```

Here is my projects show page. Clicking the "Vote for this project" button is what triggers the error.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @project.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Video url:</strong>
  <%= @project.video_url %>
</p>



<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbW-Bnm6Ipg' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>




<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @project.description %>
</p>

<br><br>


<div class="voteButton">
  <%= link_to "<button>Vote for this project</button>".html_safe, add_vote_path(:project_id => @project.id) %>
</div>
<br><br>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :votes
  resources :projects
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'projects#index'


  controller :projects do 
    get '/projects/add_vote' => 'projects#add_vote', as: :add_vote
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your route doesn't currently specify that it needs a parameter. Try this for your route instead:

```
controller :projects do
  get 'add_vote/:project_id', to: 'projects#add_vote', as: :add_vote
end
```

`rails routes` is a useful tool for debugging routing issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `rake routes` in console you will see that due to your `resources :projects` you have a `/projects/:id` route which is what `/projects/add_vote` is actually being pattern-matched to. When a new request comes in the router will look for a route match going from top to bottom of the rake routes list. To fix this you could move the lien with `resources :projects` below `add_vote`.

Also, I think it would be helpful to change your add_vote path to include the id of the project:

```
get '/projects/:id/add_vote' => 'projects#add_vote', as: :add_vote
```

This will have the added benefit of not matching `/projects/:id` as your current situation does. Your link then becomes:

```
<%= link_to "<button>Vote for this project</button>".html_safe, add_vote_path(@project) %>
```